# Override chef client log setting when bootstraping

Tags: chef-infra

I want to collect all the chef client logs to a log file. So I change the chef client log configuration from `STDOUT` to `/var/log/chef-client.log`, just apply the change on one node to `/etc/chef/client.rb`.

```
log_location     /var/log/chef-client.log
```

But when I bootstrap from a workstation, I found the chef client configuration is changed to `STDOUT` again.

So is there a way I can change the log location from server side, then when bootstrap it will override the client configuration?

Comment: bootstrap is one time command toward a node, you should not run bootstrap toward a node already registered ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing log_location during bootstrap was [recently merged](https://github.com/chef/chef/pull/5502/files), you'll need to use at least `12.17.44`. Then you can specify `config_log_location` in `knife.rb` used for bootstrap. For managing client.rb after bootstrap use [chef-client cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/chef-client).